# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, uniform-convergence

I need to check uniform convergence of the series  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+z)^2} $$ on $D$: $\vert z\vert \leq R \lt \infty$

I've tried to use Weierstrass M-test, but I can't find such convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ that $\vert\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}\vert \lt a_n$ for all $n$. Do you have any ideas?

Or maybe I can use something else instead of Weierstrass M-test?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For large $n$, $|n+z|$ if of the same ordes as $n$. This means that you can, for example, show that, for fixed $z$, and large $n$, $|n+z|^2 \ge C |n|^2$ (with some Constant $C = C(z)$)

Comment: If $R$ is large enough the domain $D$ encloses a double pole of the given function ($\psi'(z+1)$) and the convergence **cannot** be uniform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. For $n>R$ and $|z|\leq R$, we have that $|n+z|\geq n-|z|\geq n-R>0$, and
$$\left\vert\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}\right\vert \lt\frac{1}{(n-R)^2}.$$